# Parse.com Sign Up Issue - Javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Having issues with my JavaScript application using [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com).

It seems like everything is initializing properly, it's just I can't seem to save any of the data to the application. Are my functions getting called properly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Parse</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.8.min.js">

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction() {

                Parse.initialize("ID", "PASS");

                var self = this;

                var user = new Parse.User();
                var username = this.$("#signup-username").val();
                var password = this.$("#signup-password").val();

                user.signUp(null, {
                        success: function (user) {
                            alert("Yay!");
                        },
                        error: function (user, error) {
                            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                        }
                    });
            }
        </script>
        <form>Username:
            <input type="text" id="signup-username" placeholder="Username" required="yes">
            <br>Password:
            <input type="text" id="signup-password" placeholder="Password" required="yes">
            <br>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Parse documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.User.html#.signUp), `signUp` is a static method on `Parse.User` so it should be called a little differently. You also need to pass `signUp` the username and password.

```
function myFunction() {

    Parse.initialize("ID", "PASS");

    var username = $("#signup-username").val(),
        password = $("#signup-password").val();

    Parse.User.signUp(username, password, {}, {
        success: function (user) {
            alert("Yay!");
        },
        error: function (user, error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your response! I actually figured that one out on my own a little while ago. Right now I'm working on a login error. It's saying I'm not passing the proper parameters. Checkout my newest post, please.